# codeigniter session cookie not saved

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-cookies, shared-hosting

my session is not working properly

Here's my configuration:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

The session is actually saved but after redirect I lost the session data
after some troubleshooting I found out that the COOKIE ci_session is NULL and not set properly
I tried to manually set it on session.php but it's not working and even after set them to some values and imediately print the cookie the result is always NULL

but if I tried to set it on controller like this the cookie is saved just fine

```
public function test_save_cookie()
{
    $cookie = array(
        'name'   => 'home_set',
        'value'  => 'home page Change 2',
        'expire' => time()+86500,
        'domain' => '',
        'path'   => '/',
        'prefix' => '',
        );
    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    var_dump($_COOKIE['home_set']);
    var_dump($this->input->cookie('home_set',TRUE));


    setcookie(
        "asdasd",
        session_id(),
        (empty($this->_config['cookie_lifetime']) ? 0 : time()),
        '/',
        '',
        FALSE,
        TRUE
    );
    var_dump($_COOKIE['asdasd']);
}

public function test_cookie()
{
    var_dump($this->input->cookie('name',TRUE));
    var_dump($_COOKIE['home_set']);
    var_dump($_COOKIE['ci_session']);

    var_dump(session_id());
}
```

I host the codeigniter project on shared-hosting service of godaddy
On local I used PHP 5.5.15 and the server I use is using PHP 5.5.38

Comment: have loaded session library in `config/autoload.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Try storing sessions to db
Try:

```
    $config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

For mysql_database :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` blob NOT NULL,
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your session save path like,

```
 $config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'sessions';
```

and make sure `/application/sessions` is writable.

Answer (score 0):

Add a value to cookie prefix. Something like this:
$config['cookie_prefix']    = 'some_value'